# setting python logging config using dictionary fails if `incremental` is set to True?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-logging

I've got a pretty simple example, cfg1.yaml:

```
version: 1
incremental: False
formatters:
  text_fmt:
    format: "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - job_id %(job_id)s - task_id %(task_id)s - username %(username)s - %(message)s"
handlers:
  text_file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    formatter: text_fmt
    filename: job_log.txt

loggers:
  logger:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [text_file]
```

I've got a pretty simple example, cfg2.yaml (same as first one, just changed "text" to "txt":

```
version: 1
incremental: True
formatters:
  txt_fmt:
    format: "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - job_id %(job_id)s - task_id %(task_id)s - username %(username)s - %(message)s"
handlers:
  txt_file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    formatter: txt_fmt
    filename: job_log.txt

loggers:
  logger:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [txt_file]
```

and my code to load it is:

```
import yaml
from logging import config

fh = open("./cfg1.yaml") 
log_config = yaml.safe_load(fh.read())
config.dictConfig(log_config)

fh = open("./cfg2.yaml") 
log_config = yaml.safe_load(fh.read())
config.dictConfig(log_config)
```

What I get when I run it is the following error `No handler found with name 'text_file'` - full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/schapman/Workspaces/obs-demo-job-doer/converter.py", line 10, in <module>
    config.dictConfig(log_config)
  File "/Users/schapman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/logging/config.py", line 809, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Users/schapman/.pyenv/versions/3.9.18/lib/python3.9/logging/config.py", line 508, in configure
    raise ValueError('No handler found with '
ValueError: No handler found with name 'text_file'
```

If I comment out the `incremental` line in the yaml it works.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Where, exactly, does the error happen?  Is it on the `config.dictConfig()` call?  Please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: Yea, the failure is in the dictConfig call. Added the stack trace to the post.